# if $n > 1$ is an integer not of the form $6k + 3$, prove that $n^2 + 2^n$ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My proof.
By Division Algorithm, n is one of form $6 k, 6 k+1, 6 k+2, 6 k+4, 6 k+5$.
So first, If $n=6 k$, $n^2+2^n=36 k^2+2^{6 k}$. then $2$ divide it. and, divisor is not one. so, it is composite.
others prove similar way.

I solve this half. but I'm curious if $n=6 k+3$, $n^2+2^n$ is prime.
I already try, but fail... please help.

Comment: The point is not $n=6k+3, n^2+2^n$ but the other way round

Comment: Use curly braces to write exponents with multiple characters.
Ex. "$2^{6k}$" was produced by putting "2^{6k}" inside dollar signs.

Comment: @LJL oh, thanks.

Comment: Can you show that if $n$ is even so is $n^2+2^n$, and if $n\equiv\pm1\pmod6$, then $3\mid n^2+2^n$?

Comment: I'll just go ahead and spoil the fun with a counterexample:

$n = 6(4)+3$, $n^2+2^n = 73\cdot521\cdot3529$

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  oh, I just know, wrong proof... I try now

Comment: @LJL umm.. I misunderstand problem.. thanks, I'm a beginner English

Answer (score 1):

$n^2+2^{6k+5}=n^2-1+(2^{6k+5}+1)=(6k+6)(6k+4)+3(2^{6k+4}-2^{6k+3}+\cdots +1)$ is a multiple of $3$, hence is a composite number. The other cases can be done similarly.